# how to upload a audio file from iphone documents folder to server

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am recording the voice and saving it into iphone document folder but I want it to upload to the server, so how to do this?

```
    NSString * path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/%@_%@_%@_%@.wav", NSHomeDirectory(), patient.firstName, patient.lastName, patient.transactionId, type];
```

Where path is asset.path

```
 if (assetIndex < ([assets count]-1)) {
    while (assetIndex < ([assets count]-1)) {
        assetIndex += 1;
        Asset *asset = [assets objectAtIndex:assetIndex];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:asset.path];


     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [ASIHttpRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) and [jsonKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit)

```
  ASIFormDataRequest *request =  [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kServerURLString]];
 [request setData:imageData
            withFileName:@"name.png" 
          andContentType:@"image/png"
                  forKey:@"file1"];
  [request setPostValue:@"yourJson" forKey:@"yourKey"];
  [request startSynchronous];
  NSError *localError = [request error];
  NSDictionary *responseDictionary = nil;
    if(!localError){
        responseDictionary = [[request responseString] objectFromJSONString];
         NSLog(@"ResponseDict:%@",[responseDictionary description]);
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Error:%@",[localError description]);
    }
```