# how to upload audio file from documnets directory to server in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to upload a audio file from iphone documents folder to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9867340/how-to-upload-a-audio-file-from-iphone-documents-folder-to-server)

I have path where is sound file in app which i record i want to send it to server how may send this i have send image upload to server but how may i send from documets folder to server

This is the path where my files is

```
    NSString * path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/%@_%@_%@_%@.wav", NSHomeDirectory(), theCellData.firstName,theCellData.lasttName, type];
```

So may use this to upload that file to server I am uploading image from resources in this way

```
       UIImage*myImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"dr.jpg"];

        imageView.image=myImage;



   NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 1.0);
// setting up the URL to post to
   NSString *urlString = @"http://www.celeritas-solutions.com/emrapp/emr.php";

// setting up the request object now
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
  [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
  [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


   NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
   NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
  [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"dr.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];



     [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:body];

// now lets make the connection to the web
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(returnString);
```

Comment: yes my team mate also posted this but no response so i again posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP Code

```
<?php
$uploaddir = 'audio/';
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
   echo "OK";
} else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?>
```

iPhone Code:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"AudioName"];// specify your audioname

NSString *file2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filePath ofType:@"wav"];
NSData *file1Data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:file2];

NSString *urlString = @"http://www.yourdomainName.com/yourPHPPage.php";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\".wav\"\r\n"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:file1Data]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];


NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

NSLog(@"Return String= %@",returnString);
```

Comment: ok post then i can test thanks but in fileName what to give

Comment: what to give in filename which is in filePath

Comment: i updated the answer. You get audio and convert to nsdata then apply the above code

Comment: is it ok but i am asking that in dictionary my file was as i told you so how may i give that name to file for upload

Comment: I am asking about your Documents folder filename how to use that in this

Comment: what is your audio file path?

Comment: NSString * path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/%@_%@_%@_%@.wav", NSHomeDirectory(), theCellData.firstName,theCellData.lasttName, type];

Comment: this is the audio file which is in documents i want to upload

Comment: mention your audio name only?

Comment: listen i don't know the audio name which is store

Comment: this is the path where file is stored so how to get name from this

Comment: You must know Audio name or user selected as audio name or opcode the audio name until you cant get audio file from document directory.

Comment: NSString * path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/%@_%@_%@_%@.wav", NSHomeDirectory(), theCellData.firstName,theCellData.lasttName, type];  change to NSString *file2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:path ofType:@"wav"]; //apply the audio name of path to assign file2

Comment: I am giving path where i store file it returns o size audio file

Comment: do some thing like store some example audio file in documents directory and testing it. then after that u change it. ok.